# Install python caffe with anaconda2 (pycaffe)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, pycaffe

I'm trying to to be able to run this demo https://github.com/ZheC/Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation

I'm running ubuntu 14.04

I have installed Anaconda, and after installing many many many dependencies another one pops. It also requires python caffe

So I installed it with this command:
(I also tried `Pip install caffe` but if failed)

```
Conda install caffe
```

But then when I try to run it I get:

```
$python
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gtkratosman-lap/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "/home/gtkratosman-lap/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: libprotobuf.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to verify this behaviour in my own Anaconda environment running conda v4.3.27 in a Python v2.7.14 virtual environment, installing `caffe` v1.0.0rc5.

Having looked further into the issue, it seems it relates to the following open Anaconda issue: [caffe needs to pin protobuf requirement to version #6733](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6733)

As described in the issue:

> The `caffe` and `caffe-gpu` package in `defaults` has a requirement on protobuf without any version dependencies. Unfortunately, the caffe packages links to libprotobuf.so.12 which is provided by the protbuf version 3.2.0

As such, I found I was able to successfully `import caffe` in Python, running in my Anaconda virtual environment, by first manually installing protobuf v3.2.0, as follows: `conda install protobuf==3.2.0`